# How to dowload and rename dependency jars in pom.xml

Tags: maven

Here is my pom.xml which is downloading the dependency jars- jsaf-3.5.jar and mal-1.5.0.jar But I want to remove the version part from the name.That is jsaf.jar and mal.jar Please suggest how to rename those jars in the pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                  <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                  <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                  <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                  <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.qsa.jsaf</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsaf</artifactId>
          <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.mal</groupId>
          <artifactId>mal</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>   
      
    </project>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Strip version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#stripVersion) from dependencies with parameter

```
<stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
```

> Strip artifact version during copy

Sample configuration

```
<configuration>
    <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
    <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
    <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
</configuration>
```